# Pechkin - Html to pdf converter - In Console application

Tags: c#, html, pdf

Can I use https://github.com/gmanny/Pechkin this to generate pdf files in console application?

it works fine on wincows form application , although.

Any code sample for console app will help.

and can any 1 explain BeginInvoke , used in this sample

```
 private void OnScPhase(SimplePechkin converter, int phasenumber, string phasedescription)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { Text = ("New Phase " + phasenumber + ": " + phasedescription); }));
        }
        else
        {
            Text = ("New Phase " + phasenumber + ": " + phasedescription);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's definitely possible, could you post the code you're using and specify what error you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can,

The code you sent, checks if it executes in UI thread, and transfer it to UI if not, UI elements can't be access outside of the UI thread

in console, you don't need this code, just do `Console.WriteLine` instead of this

Comment: Got the BeginInvoke thing, But is it possible to use Pechkin in a console application ?

Comment: I think you can, just try to do it, and ask if you would have any issues with it

Comment: I have tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121508/pushkin-gmanny-how-to-lack-of-documentation

byte[] pdfBuf = new SimplePechkin(new GlobalConfig()).Convert(html);
File.WriteAllBytes(path, pdfBuf);

But it throws an error at 1st Line,
I have checked my html file was correct, byte conversion was also correct ..